# How to store page content with PHP function in database?

Tags: php, oracle

I'm developing my own CMS that using object PHP and Oracle as a database.

My page is running with one index.php file and including other files where I store functions.

Now I thinking about store all my pages content in database, but I prepared functions to print tables with pagination and sort functions. So when I need to include this table with any text into my post that stored in database I need to use **eval()** function.

I hear about **eval()** function to execute all functions that stored in my Oracle database, but for some reason this is not recommend solution.

What is the best way to solve this without using eval()?

Here is the part of code that I use:

**PHP Code that prints content:**

```
public static function pageContent(){
 if (isset($_GET['pid'])){
   $pid = $_GET['pid']
    $pQuery = "SELECT pcontent FROM page_base where pid = $pid";
    $connect = $_SESSION['connection'];
    $stid = oci_parse($connect, $pQuery);
    oci_execute($stid);
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        foreach($row as $item){
            echo eval($item);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

**PHP Function printing table (simplified)**

```
protected static function writeTable($argument, $color, $rpp){
     $connect = $_SESSION['connection'];
     $argument = Content::addSort($argument);
     $stid = oci_parse($connect, $argument);
     oci_execute($stid);
     $ncols = oci_num_fields($stid);
    ?>
    <div class="widget-table-title
     <?php echo $color ?>
     ">
     <?php
    Content::tableTitles($stid, $ncols);
    ?>
    </div>
     <div class="widget-table bg-white">
     <?php
    Content::fetchPage($stid, $rpp, $color);
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    Content::paginationLinks(oci_num_rows($stid),$rpp, $color);
}
```

**SQL Table**

```
create table page_base(
    pid integer primary key not null,
    ptitle varchar2(30) not null,
    pcontent varchar2(2000) not null
);
```

**SQL query to see authors**

```
class Queries{
   $showAuthors = "SELECT NAME, AGE, ADDRESS FROM AUTHORS";
   ...
}
```

**SQL query to add my page content**

```
insert into page_base values(page_base.nextval, 'Home Page', 
'?>Some text. <?php Content::writeTable(Queries::$showAuthors,"bg-
yellowplane", 50);');
```

*Queries::$showAuthors is a static variable in class that content SQL Query.*

*bg-yellowplane is just a color selector in CSS*

Comment: You should store data only in the database, HTML and layout stuff in HTML template and use PHP to get data and insert into HTML template.

Comment: In your database, store some query parameters for each page which would tell a static PHP script to either run and pull data from the database or to not run.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for developing yet another CMS from scratch? Forgive me, but that sounds a lot like inventing a wheel. Also, storing code in SQL database is usually a bad idea.